# Calculating percentage from MySQL data

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble to calculate totals from multiple from entries in MySQL with same Model (like in table 2 below).

I was able to calculate and display the total of same Model (table 1 Model entries) but I need to the sum of the values inside the same Model. I have the following tables:

Table 1:

[image: table 1]

Table 2:

[image: table 2]

This function below i'm using to count how many entries with same model:

```
function countTableT29Defective($table) { //count table rows
global $database;
$count = $database->count($table, [ "AND" => ["yk_model" => "YKT29GP"]]);
return $count;
}
```

What should I do to calculate the total of Defective for each model?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What keeps you from either writing that algorithm in an SQL query, or fetching all data and computing that "defective" in PHP code?

Comment: hi Nico, I'm not sure on how to do it in sql as I'm kind new into all this :-(

Comment: Then please share more details - where are you stuck? What have you tried to get this done?